# google action accepting character string

Tags: actions-on-google

We are currently building a google action which accepts parcel tracking codes. However, we are having great difficulty getting action to accept a string of characters. It's very unreliable in recognition.

Examples
ABAERAF
3HE9WYR

Has anyone had this challenge and do you have any recommendations to improve accuracy for recognition?

Comment: It would help if you update your question with the Intents you've tried using to recognize this and how you are expecting users to enter the characters.

Comment: Hi Prisoner, please find video of issue here: https://youtu.be/BOj6d4Dy1Rs. Hopefully this demonstrates?

Comment: This illustrates your problem, but it would also help us to see a screen shot of how you have designed the Intent. If you are using Dialogflow, please update the question with a screen shot of the Intent. If you're using the Actions SDK, please update the question with your actions.json. https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/hey-google-i-need-help-with-my-action-8cf09714a20d

Comment: Dialogflow may not work well at all for this kind of system. You may want to refactor the codes to be easier to say aloud, or perhaps add a login system/use the phone keyboard to save packages.